# How to store and run Powershell code in Excel book

Tags: excel, vba, powershell

I have a simple PS script.
I need to store it somehow in the Excel workbook as it is a shared document.
My final solution is to store the code in the cell value and then run it.
The problem is that all quotes are removed in the running script. But watch shows them just fine.
[Powershell error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oATZP.png)
[Watch variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhyYc.png)

I'm running the script in the following way:

```
strCommand = "PowerShell.exe -noexit "" " & getScript() & " "" " & host
```

Comment: Write the script to a temporary file and call that file with Powershell.  Then delete the temp file.

Comment: that is what I am doing now, thanks )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim Williams proposed the following:
Write the script to a temporary file and call that file with Powershell. Then delete the temp file. –

My solution:

```
...
path = createTempFile(scr)
...
strCommand = "PowerShell.exe -noexit -File " & path & " " & param
    retval = Shell(strCommand, vbNormalFocus)
...


...
Private Function createTempFile(str) As String
    Dim tempPath As String
    tempPath = "C:\blablabla\" & name & ".ps1"
    Dim fs As Object
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f = fs.CreateTextFile(tempPath, True)
    f.Write str
    f.Close
    
    createTempFile = tempPath

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your script to base64 and pass it to `powershell.exe`'s `-EncodedCommand` switch, this way you don't need to worry about escaping quotation marks:

```
# Read script into a string
$Script = Get-Content .\path\to\script.ps1 -Raw

# Get UTF16-encoded byte string
$ScriptUTF16 = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($Script)

# Convert to base64
$EncodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($ScriptUTF16)
```

`$EncodedCommand` now holds a long base64 string that you can copy into a cell (or a macro definition) - you can copy it to your clipboard with `Set-Clipboard` or write it to a file if desired. The syntax for invoking the resulting script will then be:

```
strCommand = "PowerShell.exe -EncodedCommand " & getBase64Script()
```

Comment: I'm not using any path to script. The string in the Excel spreadsheet itself (cell value) ! as it's shared between colleagues.

Comment: @АрсенКул you only need to do this _once_ to generate the base64 string - copy the script from excel into a text editor, save as `*.ps1`, run the code above and then copy the base64 string into excel instead of the plaintext script

Comment: thanks, BUT!
I've spent so much time trying to do something with this, but I found that I can't use such long string. It has len 3772 and I can't load it in any variable. Shorter strings working just fine